# RabbitMQ & Docker: Failed to create thread: Operation not permitted (1)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, docker-swarm

I'm using RabbitMQ in a docker swarm which has multiple services, all the other services are starting up fine, but the RabbitMQ container doesn't, and the logs show the following error:

```
Failed to create thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.6"

networks:
  rabbitmq:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

x-logging: &default-logging
  driver: json-file
  options:
    max-size: "10m"
    max-file: "5"

services:
 rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    hostname: rabbitmq
    logging: *default-logging
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=false"
    networks:
      - rabbitmq
```

I tried passing this environment variable:

```yaml
  enviroment:
    - RABBITMQ_IO_THREAD_POOL_SIZE=10 # Decreasing the number of threads
```

This was meant to decrease the number of threads in case that was the issue, but there was no difference.

What could be causing this error, and how could I go about fixing it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If that's a copy & paste of the environment you passed, you've spelled it `enviroment`, so it will have been ignored

Answer (score 2):

adding root permissions to the container can solve it

```
privileged: true
```

Comment: yeah but what is the argument for doing so ? wouldn't that create a security issue ?

Answer (score 2):

What version of `Docker` are you using?
I had the same issue using `Docker v19.03`, but updating to `Docker v24.0.5` resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the offical RabbitMQ docker image running on Azure Pipelines:

```
Failed to create thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

With the following docker-compose file:

```
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.10
    container_name: "rabbit_run_${IMAGE_TAG}"

    volumes:
      - ./config/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

I tried switching to bitnami/rabbitmq:3.11 in the same environment and this worked for me. This is however a workaround, and NOT a solution to fixing your problem with the official image:

```
  rabbit:
    image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.11
    container_name: "rabbit_run_${IMAGE_TAG}"
    volumes:
      - ./config/rabbitmq.conf:/bitnami/rabbitmq/conf/custom.conf:ro
```

Answer (score 0):

I add the same issue with Docker 18.03 , solved with docker v20.10